# Программа на tkinter не прекращает выполнение после закрытия

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть небольшая игра написанная на tkinter, в которой основная программа ждет условия завершения игры, чтобы завершить параллельный поток выполнения запущенный вот этим методом:

```
    def play(self):
       #Тут происходят всякие вычисления и перерисовка элементов
       #...
       after_time = 1000/self.k
       self.after_id = self.canv.after(after_time, self.play)
```

Больше нигде метод after() не используется. Суть проблемы в том, что когда я закрываю окно программы во время игры, то окно закрывается, а программа продолжает выполнение в командной строке и выдает вот такую ошибку:

[image: cmd]

Comment: Нашел ответ в другой теме. Если кто еще столкнулся с такой проблемой вот ссылка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168967/invalid-command-name-while-executing-after-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы код опубликовать</sup>

Не могу воспроизвести ошибку:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools
import tkinter


def loop(widget, delay_ms=300, chars=itertools.cycle('\-/|')):
    print(next(chars), end='\r', flush=True)
    widget.after(delay_ms, loop, widget, delay_ms)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # hide GUI
root.after_idle(loop, root)  # start loop
root.after(5000, root.destroy)  # quit in 5 seconds
root.mainloop()
print('done')
```

Программа успешно завершается через 5 секунд.

Можно попробовать явно все ресурсы освободить при закрытии окна `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)`, но [Tk должна сама это делать](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8454).

Можно ещё для отладки вызвать `self.canv.after_cancel(self.after_id)` на выходе, но подобное микро-управление обычно не нужно.